# Weird scanf behavior

Tags: c

So I'm a complete newbie to C. I was going to start working with linked lists when I encountered very weird scanf behavior.

scanf with empname works fine. it keeps accepting input until a newline character is encountered.

However, on pressing enter(post providing emp name), I'm unable to enter the employee profession.

And, for example, I enter 10000 as the employee salary and press enter, the printf statement isn't executed until I enter a random character(post entering 10000 and pressing enter) and press enter.

I tried writing just "%s" instead of "%[^\n]s" against the employee profession, but I'm facing the same issue as the third case.

Attaching my code below for reference

Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you!

```
struct empdetails
{
    int empid ;
    char * empname ;
    char * profession ;
    int salary;
};

typedef struct empdetails empdet ;
empdet emp1 ;
empdet * emp2 ;

emp1.empid=1 ;

emp1.empname=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char)) ;
printf("Enter employee name:") ;
scanf("%[^\n]s\n", emp1.empname) ;

emp1.profession=(char *)malloc(50*sizeof(char)) ;
printf("Enter employee profession:") ;
scanf("%[^\n]s\n", emp1.profession) ;

printf("Enter employee salary:") ;
scanf("%d\n", &emp1.salary) ;

printf("EMPID:%d  EMPNAME:%s  PROFESSION:%s  SALARY:%d", emp1.empid, emp1.empname, emp1.profession, emp1.salary) ;

free (emp1.empname);
free (emp1.profession);
```

Comment: Your format string for `emp1.empname` says there should be an `s` after the name.

Comment: `%[^\n]` matches a sequence of characters other than `\n`, then `s` matches itself literally, then `\n` matches whitespace.

Comment: As a side note, I think you should make those strings arrays with fixed size inside `empdetails` so you don't need to keep allocating small memory blocks on heap.